# htaccess rewrite folder-dash to .html

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I need to rewrite folder.html to folder/
How can I do that?

I tryed:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^folder.html(.*) folder/$1
```

But it's not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should rewrite `folder.html` to `folder/`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^folder.html folder/ [L,R=301]
```

EDIT:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^folder/ folder.html [L,R=301]
```

ANOTHER EDIT:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^folder/ folder.html [L,R=301]
```

Comment: I need the opposite, folder/ should be folder.html now it redirect folder.html to folder/ so I tryed: RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^folder/ folder.html [L,R=301] but still get the same

Comment: Try doing a hard refresh, but that should work. Is your url `example.com/folder/` or something like `example.com/abc/folder/`?

Comment: The url is www.example.com/folder/ I need to place the code in www.example.com htaccess file, so at beginning right? my full htaccess file is RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^folder/ folder.html [L,R=301] Is there a rule I could use in the folder htaccess file?

Comment: I have made another edit. Try that. It is to be places in the root folders htaccess file.

Comment: No it's not working, I guess it's impossible to rename folders to file names, I allready searched for many hours without working solutions. I guess the only way is to rewrite parameter to .html which will call the necessary PHP file. Thanks anyway

Comment: It can be done. Make sure you clear the cache of your browser when you try/use a different browser. The above does work for me. If you  remove the second and third line of the code, will the rewrite work for you?

Comment: No even by clearing browser and whole PC cache and removing second and third line it's still not working, but when you say it works by you then the problem is with my server, i'm gonna contact the host and will tell the result. I'll accept your answer, thanks